# Sort array by property in another array

Tags: php, performance, sorting, quicksort, usort

I have two arrays of the same size. One contains all product information and the other one contains only product_id and position. I want to order the first array by the order specified in the second array. Right now I have this code but there must be a more efficient way to do it.

```
        foreach ($ret_products as $ret_product) {
            foreach ($sort as $sort_product) {
                if ($ret_product->id === $sort_product['product_id']) {
                    $ret_product->sort_position = $sort_product['position'];
                }
            }
        }
         usort($ret_products, function($a, $b){ 
            return $a->sort_position > $b->sort_position;
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This removes the double for loop:

```
$order = [];
foreach ($sort as $sort_product) {
  $order[$sort_product['product_id']] = $sort_product['position'];
}

usort($ret_products, function($a, $b) use ($order) {
  return $order[$a->id] > $order[b->id];
});
```

Comment: You can also use `array_column($sort, 'position', 'product_id')` to make `$order`.

Comment: This isn't working, getting a php error saying order is undefined in the usort return

Comment: Heres the solution: 
    `usort($ret_products, function($a, $b) use($order){ 
        return $order[$a->id] > $order[$b->id];
     });`